# Cargo watch always restart

Tags: rust, file-io

I use

```
std::fs::write(".subdir/foo.txt", b"Lorem ipsum")?;
```

The file is created (or modified if already exist) but my app always restart with `cargo watch -x run`I can see logs are restarted.
If I comment this line all is fine, my app works as expected, no reload.
What is wrong ?

I try `std::fs::write`with same issue ru

Comment: The problem is that `cargo watch` listenes for file changes within the project, and writing to a file *is a filechange*, since the program is ran with a working directiory of the dir where `Cargo.toml` is and you use a relative path, `.subdir/foo.txt` is a file within the directory `cargo watch` looks for file changes in. Essentially `cargo watch` is doing what it's designed to do.

Comment: You can make `cargo watch` ignore paths with the `-i <pattern>` option.

Comment: The picked C++ tag [tag:std] is irrelevant to cargo and rust.

Answer (score 0):

adding folder to gitignore fix my issue